# How to predict data in python after training a stacked model?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm new to machine learning in python and have seen the concept of stacking models and wanted to give it a shot. The problem is i don't know how predict new data as i don't fully understand machine learning implementation in python. the code that i managed scrap looks like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error,mean_squared_error
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from vecstack import stacking
import pandas as pd

X = pd.read_csv('db/file_name3.csv')
y = pd.read_csv('db/train_labels(1).csv')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

models = [    
    CatBoostRegressor(iterations=200,
                            learning_rate=0.03,
                            depth=4,
                            loss_function='RMSE',
                            eval_metric='RMSE',
                            random_seed=99,
                            od_type='Iter',
                            od_wait=50,
                     logging_level='Silent'),

    CatBoostRegressor(iterations=500,
                            learning_rate=0.06,
                            depth=3,
                            loss_function='RMSE',
                            eval_metric='RMSE',
                            random_seed=99,
                            od_type='Iter',
                            od_wait=50,
                     logging_level='Silent'),

    ExtraTreesRegressor(random_state = 0, n_jobs = -1, 
        n_estimators = 100, max_depth = 3),

    RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 0, n_jobs = -1, 
        n_estimators = 300, max_depth = 3),

    XGBRegressor(eta=0.02,reg_lambda=5,reg_alpha=1),

    XGBRegressor(eta=0.1,reg_lambda=1,reg_alpha=10),

    XGBRegressor(eta=0.02,reg_lambda=1,reg_alpha=10,n_estimators=300),

    XGBRegressor(eta=0.012,max_depth=3,n_estimators=200),

    GradientBoostingRegressor(),

    BaggingRegressor(),
]
test1= pd.read_csv('db/Cleaned Data.csv')
S_train, S_test = stacking(models, X_train, y_train, X_train, 
    regression = True, metric = mean_absolute_error, n_folds = 10 , 
    shuffle = True, random_state = 0, verbose = 2)
model = model.fit(S_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(S_test)
print(y_pred.shape)
```

as you can see test1 is the data that i want to predict but could't figure it out. I can predict the data from my training set but not the new one. I have not changed any of the parameters of the models from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score


# load your X, y and test1 data here


RF = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 0, n_jobs = -1, 
                           n_estimators = 300, max_depth = 3)

# Validation function
n_folds = 5
def rmsle_cv(model):
    kf = KFold(n_folds, shuffle=True, 
               random_state=42).get_n_splits(X.values)
    rmse= np.sqrt(-cross_val_score(model, X.values, y.values.ravel(), 
                  scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv = kf))
    return(rmse)

score = rmsle_cv(RF)
print("Random Forest score: {:.3f} ({:.3f})\n".format(score.mean(), 
       score.std()))

RF.fit(X,y.values.ravel())
RF_train_pred = RF.predict(X)
RF_pred = RF.predict(test1)
print (RF_pred.shape)
```

Comment: yeah that is what i initially thought but got this error 
ValueError: shapes (3080,29) and (10,1) not aligned: 29 (dim 1) != 10 (dim 0)
and both my test and train contain 29 columns, i don't know this 10,1 is for.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share a sample data file.

Comment: [train_labels(1).csv](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/d78f4122b0b6a81c6ab8e5c14e5cc7a0/train_labels(1).csv) this is the y for the training

[file_name3.csv](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/99b739531d9cd351ce774712ef6e1010/file_name3.csv) this is the X for the training

[Cleaned Data.csv](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/c36ca35fb7069904f5c80bc0a08d0356/Cleaned%20Data.csv) values i want to predict y for

Comment: I can't download the file `Cleaned Data.csv`. Try uploading it again without a space in the file name.

Comment: [link](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/3e13204154c29a1d49d996cdcfc5edd6/Cleaned_Data.csv)

Comment: I am not sure about `S_train, S_test = stacking(...)` commands. Since I do not have it installed, I can't run it at the moment. So I just used **Gradient Boosting Regressor** without using the `train_test_split` function. I updated my answer. May be you find it helpful.